# Waiting for promise result before updating templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I got a question concerning the .save() method in Ember-Data.

Normally, as I read in the docs, you should use it that way :

```
this.set('model.title', newTitle);
this.get('model').save();
```

The problem is : what if I have bind properties in my template and I want to wait for the successful save before refreshing the templates?

The first line of code automatically refreshes the templates with the bind properties, and I want to wait for the successful changes from my server.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_better-caching-defaults-for-code-findall-code-and-code-findrecord-code - specifically look at `reload: true` to force an update before continuing.

Comment: this.get('model').save().then(function(saved) { saved.set('title', newTitle)} ;

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ember-buffered-proxy](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy). Your `route.js` and `template.hbs` files will look something like the ones below:

```
//route.js

setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);

  controller.set('bufferedModel', BufferedProxy.create({
    content: model
  });
}

actions: {
  save: {
    this.get('model').save().then(() => {
      bufferedModel.applyBufferedChanges();
    }
  }
}
//template.hbs

//replace

{{model.title}}

//with

{{bufferedModel.content.title}}
```